# Node JS Insert JSON into MongoDB error: SocketException handling request

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, insert

I've been trying to insert a JSON file into mongo (100K documents), but the insert ceases at about 40K-- note that mongoimport fails also.

Pre-work:  JSON file is correct per jslint and is not complex (each document is 13 key:values and contain only alpha-numeric characters. max length of any given document is ~140 characters) and the array length is the correct 100K.

I figure it might be one of these issues, but I can't find a solution on the interwebz

- callback issue
- memory issue (loading entire file into memory)
- poorly written code (blame me)
- a-synch issue
- readFile versus readStream (this is where my intention lies)
- else

Here is my code(any help is appreciated):

```
function connectAndInsert() {
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb:...', {db: {native_parser: true}}, function(err, db) {
        if(err) throw err;
        var collection = db.collection('sofiaM');
        for (var i = 0; i < items[0].length; i++) {
            collection.insert(JSON.parse(items[0][i]), {safe: true}, function(err, docs) {
                if(err) throw err;
            })
        }
    })
};

function readJSON(callback) {
    fs.readFile('/JSON', {encoding: 'utf8'}, function (err, data) {
        if(err) throw err;
        var jDA = data.toString().split('\n');
        items.push(jDA);
        callback();
    });
};
```

Update: I didn't realize that the 16MB limit on MongoDB was for the entirety of the documents, not just a single document. I fixed this issue with a split on the Original file. Not optimal, but it worked. I would prefer to stream as a workaround and I need to fix the Unexpected end of Input Error that I am getting from the parse.

Update on Parse Error: My Items array had a null [ '' ] as the last element. The iterator counts this in the length, but JSON errors on the parse. items.pop() fixed the issue.

Comment: What happens when it fails? I'd suggest you maybe consider an async library (like npm `async`) that would allow you to iterate through the objects with more limited parallelization as a test. But the fact that it fails at the same place even with an import makes me wonder if it's not something else that is the problem. Having more information about the error would be helpful.

Comment: @WiredPrairie. Ah yes. The error is: Unexpected End of Input at Parse (native). Which suggests that my JSON is not entirely loaded. perhaps the async will help, or I will need to adjust my code to fix. Thanks for the advice and I'll test and update as needed.

Comment: Where is the code failing with that error?

Comment: @WiredPrairie the code is failing on connectAndInsert with errors: Object.parse; js:21:26; mongo_client.js:431:11 and process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13). My research suggests that it is due to connectAndInsert not having an end once my for loop hits the last item in the array. I am working on a closure or perhaps using readStream. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I see an update -- each single document can be 16MB in MongoDB. A single collection can grow massively. You're not hitting the latter.